# Meta Programming Puzzle: Counting Plus-Signs on a Cartesian Plane

Tags: algorithm, performance, logic

I'm attempting to solve one of Meta's "Level 4" coding puzzles, "Mathematical Art".  The coding puzzles can be accessed here: https://www.metacareers.com/profile/coding_puzzles/

(note that you will need to create an account to access the puzzles)

For convenience, I'll attach an image of the prompt here, along with have it written out below:
[Puzzle Prompt and Constraints, taken from Meta's coding puzzle site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGeak.png)

"You are creating a special painting on a canvas which may be represented as a 2D Cartesian plane. You start by placing a thin brush at the origin (0,0) and then make *N* axis-aligned strokes without lifting the brush off of the canvas. For the *i*th stroke, you'll move your brush L​<sub>i</sub> units from its current position in a direction indicated by the character D<sub>i</sub>, which is either U (up), D (down), L (left), or R (right), while leaving behind a line segment of paint between the brush's current and new positions. For example, if L<sub>1</sub>=5 and D<sub>1</sub>= L, you'll draw a stroke between coordinates (0,0) and (−5,0), with your brush ending up at coordinates (−5,0). Note that each stroke is either horizontal or vertical, and that each stroke (after the first) begins where the previous stroke ended.

This painting is being marketed as a work of mathematical art, and its value is based on the number of times a certain mathematical symbol appears in it −− specifically, the plus sign. A plus sign is considered to be present at a certain position if and only if, for each of the 4 cardinal directions (up, down, left, and right), there's paint leading from the point in that direction (or, vice versa, leading to that point from that direction). Note that the paint from arbitrarily many strokes of your brush might come together to form any given plus sign, and that at most one plus sign may be considered to exist at any given position.

Determine the number of positions in the painting at which a plus sign is present."

We are also given the constraints:
2 ≤ N ≤ 2,000,000

1 ≤ L<sub>i</sub> ≤ 1,000,000,000

D<sub>i</sub> should be contained in the set {U, D, L, R}

To summarize, the problem is basically as follows.
We are given:

- (integer) N axis-aligned strokes
- (List of integers) L for length of each stroke
- (string) D to denote the direction of each stroke as Up (U), Down (D), Left (L), Right (R)

and we need to determine the number of plus signs these strokes would form if painted.

As an example, given the input:

```
N = 9
L = [6, 3, 4, 5, 1, 6, 3, 3, 4]
D = ULDRULURD
```

The "painting" that would be generated would look like this:
[Sample input given for this puzzle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r22NV.png)

And we would expect to receive an output of 4, indicated by the red dots in the image.

After a decent deal of time spent trying to solve this, the best approach I've come up with so far follows the following general steps:

1. Create lists of horizontal and vertical lines, with each list element containing line start and end points and value on unused axis
2. Order these lines such that the start point is always the lower value between the start and end point (i.e. a line that started at `x = 0` and ending at `x = -4` would instead be denoted as starting at `x = -4` and ending at `x = 0`.  Since the direction of the lines does not matter after the drawing has been finished, this should be alright to do, mainly to avoid some headache later.)
3. Merge lines on the same axis that intersect or overlap. (For example, a line of `-2 ≤ x ≤ 0, y = 2` would be merged with a line of `0 ≤ x ≤ 2, y = 2` to produce the line `-2 ≤ x ≤ 2, y = 2`
4. Get valid coordinates from the two sets of merged lines - in other words, get all possible coordinates the lines cover aside from start and end points, as these would not be capable of producing plus sign since there is no more to the line segment beyond the start / end point.
5. Compare the two sets of valid coordinates derived from the two merged line lists.  Every coordinate shared between the two sets is equivalent to 1 plus sign.

Currently, the code (written in Python) I have to solve this problem looks like this:

```
from typing import List

def getPlusSignCount(N: int, L: List[int], D: str) -> int:
    pos = [0, 0]
    x_lines = []
    y_lines = []
    plus_sign_count = 0

    for stroke in range(0, len(L)):
        if D[stroke] == "U":
            y_lines.append([[pos[1], pos[1] + L[stroke]], pos[0]])
            pos[1] = pos[1] + L[stroke]
        elif D[stroke] == "D":
            y_lines.append([[pos[1], pos[1] - L[stroke]], pos[0]])
            pos[1] = pos[1] - L[stroke]
        elif D[stroke] == "L":
            x_lines.append([[pos[0], pos[0] - L[stroke]], pos[1]])
            pos[0] = pos[0] - L[stroke]
        elif D[stroke] == "R":
            x_lines.append([[pos[0], pos[0] + L[stroke]], pos[1]])
            pos[0] = pos[0] + L[stroke]

    # order line start / end values to be from least to greatest
    # in order to merge later
    for x in range(0, len(x_lines)):
        if x_lines[x][0][0] > x_lines[x][0][1]:
            x_lines[x] = [[x_lines[x][0][1], x_lines[x][0][0]], x_lines[x][1]]
    for y in range(0, len(y_lines)):
        if y_lines[y][0][0] > y_lines[y][0][1]:
            y_lines[y] = [[y_lines[y][0][1], y_lines[y][0][0]], y_lines[y][1]]


    # merge line that intersect
    def merge_lines(lines):
        merged_lines = []
        for line in lines:
            for existing_line in merged_lines:
                if line[1] == existing_line[1]:
                    if line[0][1] >= existing_line[0][0] and line[0][0] <= existing_line[0][1]:
                        existing_line[0] = [min(line[0][0], existing_line[0][0]), max(line[0][1], existing_line[0][1])]
                        break
            else:
                merged_lines.append(line)
        return merged_lines

    x_lines = merge_lines(x_lines)
    y_lines = merge_lines(y_lines)

    # get valid coordinates from both lines (ie don't include line start / end points
    vaLid_xline_coords = set()
    valid_yline_coords = set()

    for line in x_lines:
        for i in range(line[0][0] + 1, line[0][1]):
            vaLid_xline_coords.add((i, line[1]))

    for line in y_lines:
        for i in range(line[0][0] + 1, line[0][1]):
            valid_yline_coords.add((line[1], i))

    for coordinate in vaLid_xline_coords:
        if coordinate in valid_yline_coords:
            plus_sign_count += 1

    return plus_sign_count
```

At the moment, this solves the 3 sample cases Meta provides, and successfully solves 21 of the 33 test cases Meta subjects it to on submission.

Of the 12 it is failing, the following issues are present

- Memory limit exceeded on 3 test cases
- runtime error on 1 test case
- time limit exceeded on 2 test cases
- wrong answer on 6 test cases

This suggests (at least) the following to me:

- memory usage could be better optimized
- run time could be better optimized
- There are (edge?) cases that my function cannot handle

I've racked my brain a decent amount on this, and haven't come up with anything definite.  My first instincts are that

- the merge_lines logic and / or the way I'm maintaining the lines could be improved for a better runtime / memory usage
- there is some library I haven't thought to use that would allow for a different approach and improve runtime or memory usage

Unfortunately the inputs for the failing test cases are not provided, and I haven't been able to find much else on this problem elsewhere online.  Evidently the logic being used is good enough for a decent number of cases, but fails for others that I'm not able to see.  Any help or points in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Edit 1: Thanks to the suggestion from @btilly, I implemented some sorting on the lines before merging - this in turn allowed for me to only merge groups of lines that I already knew were on the same x- or y-level and intersecting, without iterating through every line.  I also changed the logic for getting the total number of plus signs to use two sets of valid coordinates and take their intersection.  This seems to have solved at least a decent deal of the issues I was having previously, as I'm now getting correct answers on 28/33 of the test cases, with the 5 incorrect ones being Memory Limit Exceeded.  I'll tinker with it a bit more and hopefully resolve those as well.

Comment: *"...I'll attach an image of the prompt here"*: please don't post images of text. Type the text.

Comment: If the painting is very big, you don't have time to paint each individual square.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat unless you're a pointillist

Comment: This is supposed to be a hard problem. Anything like a double loop in your merge logic will be too slow - you need to do things like use a sort. And don't forget, there can be `O(N^2)` pluses to find. You can't just count them. (OK, I got 31/33 of them when I did.)

Comment: @btilly Thank you for the suggestions, with them I was able to make some changes and improve up to 28/33.  Barring anything unexpected, it looks like now it will be a matter of improving memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the most interesting problem they have along with conveyor chaos (which is trickier imho).

You are along the right track with the merging of lines (to avoid counting multiple times the crosses), but after that, you need to end up with some n*log(n) algorithm to finish all the tests in time, otherwise, you will never finish the test cases in time.

Therefore, you will need some kind of red-black tree for both L4 problems, so you will have to use a library like sortedcontainers or something equivalent.

Once you have merge your lines, you need to pick one direction to sweep (n), and find a way to count crosses with a log(n) operation.

I hope it will be enough to put you in the right direction.

If you still cannot find a solution, there is a solution in the language you used (Python) here: https://github.com/seb-pg/meta_puzzles/blob/main/py3/l4_mathematical_art.py